# Trying to build binutils with --enable-gold

Tags: binutils, gold-linker

Following instructions from this site: http://llvm.org/docs/GoldPlugin.html

From the command:

```
../binutils/configure --enable-gold --enable-plugins --disable-werror
```

I get a warning saying:

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-gold
```

From this point, I can't continue building the project. Any advise?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you are in a sibling folder of `binutils`? I copied the command from the instructions but forgot that I was in a different directory and picked up a different configure script.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. the problem was that I created a build directory within binutils and there is a binutils/binutils/configure as well which caused the error. Thanks.